# Disable head-tracking for Cardboard in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

How can I disable the head-tracking for my google Cardboard Application in Unity? I want to create a controller based movement and as a result of this i want to disable that the camera moves, when the head is moving.
I found a few solutions for this, but these are for older SDK versions and these are not working anymore.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I am using Unity 2017.3.1